# NSHourCalendarUnit and NSMinuteCalendarUnit are deprecated. How to split up hours and minutes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I have implemented NSCalendarUnit in my project to split hours and minutes . Here is the code..

```
[calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit |  NSSecondCalendarUnit ) fromDate:[df dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",workendTime_txtfld.text]]];
```

In IOS8, `NSHourCalendarUnit`,`NSMinuteCalendarUnit`,`NSSecondCalendarUnit` these all are deprecated now how to handle this issue. Kindly let me know the solution for this issue..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They've been replaced by `NSCalendarUnitMinute`, `NSCalendarUnitSecond`, etc. When you type `NSMinuteCalendarUnit` into your code (in Xcode 6.1 anyway), it should give you a warning, that if you read it, tells you the new values.

Comment: In Xcode 6.4 it does provide you with a warning, with the "new value". But, when you input the "new value" it throws a compiler warning. Because the OS does not recognize the "new value".

Answer (score 1):

These are new functions of calendar.

```
 NSCalendarUnitSecond | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitHour |
 NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear;
```